# Base MySQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Sobre um sistema web ao estilo DropBox (Mas não para armazenamento), onde o usuário loga e já é redirecionado para sua HOME (Página Inicial), onde tem acesso aos seus recursos.

Alguma ideia de como trabalhar essas informações, quanto a criação das tabelas, pois não sei se o melhor é ter uma base apenas e trabalhar com prefixos ou se cada usuário teria sua prória tabela.

Comment: Bem vindo ao stack overflow. Poderia esclarecer melhor a sua dúvida? não está muito clara. Leia mais em [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em PHP você vai trabalhar com a implementação de "SESSÕES" e "CONEXÃO COM O BANCO", é só da uma pequena pesquisa que diversos conteúdos, como também sistemas prontos irão aparecer para você.

Em relação a sua duvida da base de dados, creio que precise estudar um pouco mais sobre banco de dados relacionais e como modelar uma boa base de dados.

Você não precisa criar uma base de dados para cada usuário, apenas estabeleça as entidades necessárias para o sistema e seus respectivos relacionamentos.